# parameters dictionary contains null entry for parameter 'departmentId'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Employee
    public ActionResult Index(int departmentid)
    {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

        List<Employee> employees = employeeContext.Employees
                                                  .Where(emp => emp.DepartmentId == departmentid)
                                                  .ToList();

        return View(employees);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {       
           EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

           Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees
                                              .Single(x => x.EmployeeId == id);

           return View(employee);
    }
}
```

`departmentid` is parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'departmentId' of non-nullable type.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You need to clarify what your problem is and what you need to solve that problem.  There isn't enough information here to help solve your problem.  Please edit your post and you will have a much better chance to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `departmentid` while calling the specific end point from your client.

If the parameter is optional set a default value to that parameter like below

`public ActionResult Index(int departmentid=0)`

Or make it nullable

`public ActionResult Index(int? departmentid)`